# grand parent is handling custom event emitted instead of parent in Angular 17

Tags: angular, events

I have a component called **ImageUpload** that handles pictures upload and then emit the values.
I use that component inside a component called **IngredientForm** and it works, the problem is inside **IngredientForm** there's another component called **ModifyIngredientModal** where i use **ImageUpload** again and when the event is emitted from there then it's handled with the method i've wrote inside **IngredientForm** and not the one from **ModifyIngredientModal**.

Basically the grand-parent is handling the child event instead of the parent.

this is the code of **ModifyIngredientModal**

```
  <app-image-upload
    [label]="'recipes.editor.ingredients.picture' | transloco"
    [inputName]="'ingredientPicture'"
    (photoUploaded)="uploadNewPicture($event)">
  </app-image-upload>

  uploadNewPicture(uploadedPictures: customFile[]) {
    console.log("MODIFY")
    if (uploadedPictures[0]) {
      this.ingredientPicture = uploadedPictures[0];
      this.ingredientForm.controls.ingredientPicture.setValue(true)
    } else {
      this.ingredientForm.controls.ingredientPicture.setValue(false)
    }
  }
```

and this is the one from **IngredientForm**

```
 <app-image-upload
   #ingredientPictureUpload
   [label]="'recipes.editor.ingredients.picture' | transloco"
   [inputName]="'ingredientPicture'"
   (photoUploaded)="getIngredientUploadedPhoto($event)">
 </app-image-upload>

  getIngredientUploadedPhoto(uploadedPictures: customFile[]) {
    console.log("FORM")
    if (uploadedPictures[0]) {
      this.ingredientPicture = uploadedPictures[0];
      this.ingredientForm.controls.ingredientPicture.setValue(true)
    } else {
      this.ingredientPicture = null;
      this.ingredientForm.controls.ingredientPicture.setValue(false)
    }
  }
```

in the console i can only see FORM printed, i was expecting that the parent would handle the event and it stops there, i could understand the event being handled by both of them but surely not having only the grand parent handling it

Comment: You need to share more code, or better create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Angular's outputs have very little in common with events besides naming, and they never bubble.

Comment: Please create an example on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: i'll have to check better tonight, i've tried to make a little example using the same logic from my project on stackblitz and it worked without problem